# JComboBox - Shorten KeyPress Listener

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, keypress

While the focus on a JComboBox, pressing keys in succession causes it to select the list item starting with those characters, in order. How would I shorten the amount of time allowed between each key press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled in the `BasicComboBoxUI` class where you will find code like:

```
Long l = (Long)UIManager.get("ComboBox.timeFactor");
timeFactor = l == null ? 1000L : l.longValue();
```

Which basically says the default is 1 second in order for keys pressed in succession to be concatenated together.

To override this value you need to update the UIManager with your default value before you create your combo box:

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.timeFactor", new Long(500));
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( ... );
```

Comment: I've never used UIManager before, but why do I need the ternary operator here? What would happen if I just have `Long l` and no `Long  timeFactor`?

Comment: @MollyTaylor, You don't need the first two lines of code. I was just showing you how the default "time factor" is determined by the combo box UI. If you don't add a value to the UIManager then the value returned by the get(...) method will be null so  the default is 1000 (or 1 second).

Comment: Oh okay. I'm actually using NetBeans so I can't put the `UIManager.put` directly above the comboBox initialization. I put it above the `initComponents()` call, however, which initializes all of my swing components at the beginning of the method, and I'm not seeing any difference in performance.

Comment: Sorry, I would move this over to a discussion group but I don't know how to.

Comment: The UIManager put() just needs to be done before the component is created. I never use an IDE to generate code so I don't know where you add it in your code. It is hard to judge the time when you go from 1000 to 500. Try changing the time to 4000. This will give you 4 seconds to type in the second character and it will still be appended to the first character. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So all you need is a JFrame with a single combo box and some items added to the combo box.